# Problema al guardar archivo tipo byte[] en SQL

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en C#, en la cuál necesito guardar documentos en la DB alojada en SQL Server, en la tabla de la base de datos determine un campo ***varbinary(MAX)*** y desde C# estoy mandando un byte, sin embargo me arroja el siguiente problema:

> *No se permite la conversión implícita de varchar a varbinary, utilice la función CONVERT para realizar esta consulta.*

Para que el usuario pueda seleccionar el archivo uso el siguiente bloque de código

```
 private void btnExplorador_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Todos los archivos (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtDoc.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
        openFileDialog1.Dispose();
    }
```

Para guardarlo:

```
 try
            {
                byte[] file = null;
                Stream myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                myStream.CopyTo(ms);
                file = ms.ToArray();

                bool insertado = manipulacion.insertarCapacitacion(txtNombre.Text, dtpEmision.Text, dtpVencimiento.Text, txtOrganizacion.Text, openFileDialog1.SafeFileName, file, lblID.Text);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                messages.error(e);
            }
```

Por ultimo, mi query a la base de datos es la siguiente:

```
query = ($"INSERT INTO tblCapacitaciones (nombreCapacitacion, fechaEmision, fechaVencimiento, organizacionCapacitora, realName, doc, personal) VALUES ('{nombre}', '{fechaEmision}', '{fechaVencimiento}', '{organizacion}', '{realName}', '{documento}', '{personal}')");
```

En donde el campo **"documento"** es del tipo **byte[]**

No encuentro donde este el error, espero puedan ayudarme, gracias!.

EDIT. 
El método de inserción es el siguiente:

```
public bool insertarCapacitacion(string nombre, string fechaEmision, string fechaVencimiento, string organizacion, string realName, byte[] documento, string personal)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        dbAccess = false;
        bool insertado = false;
        DataSet insertar = new DataSet();
        query = ($"INSERT INTO tblCapacitaciones (nombreCapacitacion, fechaEmision, fechaVencimiento, organizacionCapacitora, realName, doc, personal) VALUES ('{nombre}', '{fechaEmision}', '{fechaVencimiento}', '{organizacion}', '{realName}', '{documento}', '{personal}')");
        dbAccess = controller.AbrirConexion();
        if (dbAccess)
        {
            controller.adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, controller.dbConnection);
            controller.adapter.Fill(insertar, "tblCapacitaciones");
            insertado = true;
        }

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        return insertado;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar tu imprementacion del metodo `manipulacion.insertarCapacitacion`?

Comment: Ya edite el post con el método @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver

Comment: ¿Has intentado usar el CONVERT como te indica? Algo así: `query = ($"INSERT INTO tblCapacitaciones (nombreCapacitacion, fechaEmision, fechaVencimiento, organizacionCapacitora, realName, doc, personal) VALUES ('{nombre}', '{fechaEmision}', '{fechaVencimiento}', '{organizacion}', '{realName}', CONVERT(VARBINARY, '{documento}'), '{personal}')");`